# Is there a function to get count of attributes based on property in JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

If I have an array of elements as:

```
const sources = [
    { id : 0, type : "Project" },
    { id : 1, type : "Board" },
    { id : 2, type : "Fan" },
    { id : 3, type : "Project" },
    { id : 4, type : "Project" },
    { id : 5, type : "Fan" }
]
```

is there an array function I can use to get the counts mapped in to the following (without going through a for loop)

```
{
    "Project": 3 ,
    "Board": 1 ,
    "Fan": 2 
}
```

Comment: your objects are not valid javascript for a start (now fixed) - and, no, there's no built-in function that does exactly what you want, you have to write it yourself (hint: Array reduce)

Answer (score 2):

Array reduce can do what you want:

```js
const sources = [
    { id : 0, type : "Project" },
    { id : 1, type : "Board" },
    { id : 2, type : "Fan" },
    { id : 3, type : "Project" },
    { id : 4, type : "Project" },
    { id : 5, type : "Fan" }
]

// solution
const answer=sources.reduce((r,{type})=>(r[type]=(r[type]||0)+1,r),{});


console.log(answer);
```